# Palo Suite 3.1, Ubuntu, missing OLAP Server

Tags: ubuntu, olap, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I just installed Palo Suite 3.1 with the archive I got form the official web site.
I am running Ubuntu 10.04.
Once installed and logged in I got the surprise to do not have the "OLAP Server" menu.

Does anyone know if there is something extra to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Palo OLAP Manager is only for Premium version, not the community version :

http://www.jedox.com/en/products/palo-community-vs-premium-edition.html

Comment: In the link you sent me I can see that PALO OLAP is selectionned for Community version. Does it mean one can still produce OLAP cube with the community version ? Merci.